# angular2 rc5 router service singleton

Tags: angular

I've recently migrated to Angular 2 RC 5 and converted the sub-modules in my app to NgModule.

Given the following [plunker](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html) provided in the [Angular2 Routing Documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html), how can the CrisisService in the CrisisCenterModule be turned into a stateful singleton that is share across the routes of the crisis-center module.

Currently a new CrisisService is instantiated for every route in the module.

e.g. if you add a simple constructor in the CrisisService, like so:

```
constructor() {
  console.log("Hello from CrisisService");
}
```

The browser console will log out that string every time you link to a different sub-route, e.g. /crisis-center or /crisis-center/11

I'd like to be able to share state across the components in a module via a service that is cleared whenever you route away from this module, without moving the service into a global shared model.

Thank You

Comment: I found a solution providing the service in the RootModule (AppModule) and not in the Submodule (CrisisCenterModule). I do now know if it is a bug or if it is the right behaviour. If you find any documentation about this, please, let me know or I'll open an issue in the Angular2 github repo.

Comment: I made a plunker to show the case http://plnkr.co/edit/iy6zV9NJL3r8EtcqvRqU

Comment: @vinagreti I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11125) on the angular2 github repo.

Comment: I think this issue is still persist. Or may be I am doing any specific configuration mistake. Here is my another question with same topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981306/service-is-not-being-singleton-for-angular2-router-lazy-loading-with-loadchildre

Answer (score 1):

Edited answer 2016 Dec 05 at 11:14:

The problem was a bug and was fixed in https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11125.

So, now you can load the service at any module, not only in the app, and you will have a singleton for it's children.

Old answer - 2016 Aug 22 at 20:20:

I found a solution providing the service in the RootModule (AppModule) and not in the Submodule (CrisisCenterModule).

I do now know if it is a bug or if it is the right behaviour.

If you find any documentation about this, please, let me know or I'll open an issue in the Angular2 github repo.

Comment: Is it a lazy-loaded module? Then you need `forRoot()` otherwise it should be the default (application-wide singleton).

Comment: It is a lazy-load module. But I did not understand where to call the `forRoot()` method. I did this plunker to show the problem. Maybe you can edit it to solve this. http://plnkr.co/edit/iy6zV9NJL3r8EtcqvRqU thanks

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, can you change this plunker to use `forRoot()` method? http://plnkr.co/edit/iy6zV9NJL3r8EtcqvRqU

Comment: I am also looking for the answer of this problem. I do not want to put my child module services to app module. Then I can not keep loosely coupled feature.

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh, this was fixed in https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11125

Comment: I think Still the issue is there in version 2.2.1

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh Actually it is already fixed, I've checked this in one of my apps. Maybe you are having another problem. Can you place a new question in SO with your scenario? Put your model structure, so we can better understand your app. I think that is the better way to help you find a solution. Plunks is not acce

Comment: Actually I am trying to create a plunker for that. But I am facing different problem for lazy loading in plunker. Here is the Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/zgMigHSEFXxxwUp8QQzr?p=preview and here is the question. Which is I am facing now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40971268/how-to-create-plunker-for-angular2-lazyloading-router-with-loadchildren

Comment: Here is my new question. Can you please check it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981306/service-is-not-being-singleton-for-angular2-router-lazy-loading-with-loadchildre

Answer (score 0):

Like m32da1 says, the Service is only used in the CrisisCenterModule. What I did lazy load my routes:

```
export const routes: Routes = [ 
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' }, 
{ path: 'crisis', loadChildren: 'app/crisis-center/crisisCenter.module' } 
...
```

and add the CrisisServices as a provider in the crisisCenter module

If you are planning to use it in other components/routes as well, you can make it an singleton: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module-for-root

Add a shared.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }        from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HeroesModule } from './heroes/heroes.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { DialogService }  from './dialog.service';
import { CrisisService }  from './crisis-center/crisis.service';
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, RouterModule ],
    declarations: [],
    exports: [
        CommonModule, FormsModule, RouterModule]
})
export class SharedModule {

    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: SharedModule,
            providers: [DialogService, CrisisService],
        };
    }
}
```

And add the SharedModule.forRoot to the imports in the app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent }       from './app.component';
import { routing,
         appRoutingProviders } from './app.routing';

import { HeroesModule } from './heroes/heroes.module';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

import { DialogService }  from './dialog.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
    routing,
    HeroesModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    appRoutingProviders
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: Marcel, can you provide some plunker with your solution? Where to call the forRoot method?

Comment: The CrisisService is really only used by the CrisisCenterModule, so elevating it to the app scope would defeat the purpose, i.e. the CrisisService must unload when then user routes to a different module, like the HeroModule.