# How to create plunker for angular2 lazyloading router with loadChildren

Tags: angular

I am facing problem to create a pluker for demonstration an issue.
While I am using `{ path: 'mod1', loadChildren: 'mod1.module#Mod1Module'}` for my routes. Then plunker is trying to load an url like this:

https://run.plnkr.co/XXXXXXXXXX/mod1.module

But it is returning not found so my plunker is not running.

Here is the plunker URL : https://plnkr.co/edit/Qd8MLYNQVS2NJ6vH3ZC6?p=preview

**Update**

I have been able to open the dashboard with this plunker. 
https://plnkr.co/edit/zgMigHSEFXxxwUp8QQzr?p=preview
And it is showing another error while I try to navigate in Page 1 of Module 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just load the routes in the module and your app should work as in this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kFgeTn5ncMCQhae1mHMW?p=preview):

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    Mode1RoutingModule
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class Mod1Module { }
```

Comment: This is wrong. Plunkr does use the latest angular2 version. To check it, just open `config.js`. You'll see : `paths: { 'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/' }` and `map: {'@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js'}`. Just open this file and you'll see in the header : `@license Angular v2.2.4`

Comment: You are right. The plunker is working with the last version. The problem now leaves in your routing configuration. You are trying to loading routes that does not exists...

Comment: You really should stop to update continuously your answer. Comments doesn't make any sense at all, and you're loosing everyone :). Please write EDIT 1, EDIT 2, etc at the end of the post or remove and create another answer.

Comment: Thanks @Maxime. I'll do this if I need to update the answer again!

Answer (score 2):

**mod1.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    Mode1RoutingModule, // <== add this line
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    routedComponents,
    Mod1Page1Component,
    Mod1Page2Component
  ],
  providers: [
        Mod1AbcService
  ]
})
export class Mod1Module { }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/zHso2uuvHec4FHOHGjNH?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I found a bug in angular router few months ago and I made a Plunkr to demonstrate. (The bug's now fixed !).

Anyway, I used loadChildren to lazy load a module. It might help you :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'emails', component: EmailsComponent},
  {path: 'auxiliary', outlet: 'aux', component: AuxiliaryComponent},
  {path: 'contacts', loadChildren: 'app/contacts/contacts.module#ContactsModule'},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'emails'}
];
```

The full Plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/ik9lQw971X638ZATLgHR?p=preview

**EDIT 1 :**

I took a look to your Plunkr and I got it working :
https://plnkr.co/edit/l9oijQwwnXD0mz5FI10h?p=preview

**Here's what I did :**
 - Rename the file `mod1.module.ts` to `src/mod1.module.ts`
 - Change to `redirectTo` from `redirectTo: '/mod1/page1'` to `redirectTo: '/mod1'` (you do not declare a path `'/mod1/page1'` so you can't do that
- use a path like that to lazy load : `{ path: 'mod1', loadChildren: app/mod1.module#Mod1Module'}`

Comment: I have introduced Page1 Component in module 1. But still it is not working. https://plnkr.co/edit/Iegw8rQXeHxd1xfGmqGH?p=preview

Comment: `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'mod1/page1'` as I said earlier, you don't have any route matching this URL. Or your Plunkr is not up to date.

Comment: Ok I think you misunderstood something. You need to have a defined route in your `src/app.ts` `Routes` variable.

Comment: Then please help me to load the Page 1 of module 1 as my first page.

Comment: Update the question will little progress.