# Service is not being singleton for angular2 router lazy loading with loadChildren

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Here is the pluker.
https://plnkr.co/edit/tsNlmRth4mRzz0svGWLK?p=preview

In which I have created two module with two components and one service each.
I want the service should be singleton (save state) in the module level.

If you click on 'Module 1 Page 1' and 'Module 2 Page 2' It will display two different random numbers. As I am generating this number in constructor. So the service is being created each time page change. But module2 is behaving perfectly.

Note:
Mode1Module is using `loadChildren`
Mode2Module is using `children`

I found this same type issue is been fixed earlier as per this [angular2 rc5 router service singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39087873/angular2-rc5-router-service-singleton/)

But I think still it is there. So please help me to solve this out.

Comment: Is it working? What is the problem in your plunker? I saw the same message in pages 1 and 2 and I think that is the right behaviour, isn't it? Are you having another problem?

Comment: If you check Page 1, Page 2 for module 1. It is different. But for Module 2 is same. Where as Both the module's Page 1 and Page 2 will be same.

Comment: You are right, the problem still there and we can see it in your plunker. I've tested locally, with angular-cli and the bug persistis. You can place a message in this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11125 include your plunker link so they can see the bug. Reference to this SO Question and say that we've tested with system.js and angular-cli. Thanks!

Comment: The NgModule FAQ clearly states that this is not supported. if you need this, then just don't add the provider to the lazy loaded module but instead add it to an eager loaded module.

Comment: If this is the scenario then, "sharing data in lazy loaded module only" is clearly not possible via shared services. Any way we need to use eager loaded module for it. Am I right?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Lazy loaded modules have their own root scope. Providers added to lazy loaded modules get an instance in that root scope instead of the root scope of the application. 
If you add the provider to a module that is not lazy loaded, only a single instance at the application root scope will be created.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-lazy-loaded-module-provider-visibility

> **Why is a service provided in a lazy loaded module visible only to that
>   module?**
>   Unlike providers of the modules loaded at launch, providers of
>   lazy loaded modules are module-scoped.
>
> When the Angular router lazy-loads a module, it creates a new
>   execution context. That context has its own injector which is a direct
>   child of the application injector.
>
> The router adds the lazy module's providers and the providers of its
>   imported modules to this child injector.
>
> These providers are insulated from changes to application providers
>   with the same lookup token. When the router creates a component within
>   the lazy loaded context, Angular prefers service instances created
>   from these providers to the service instances of the application root
>   injector.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-why-bad

> **Why is it bad if SharedModule provides a service to a lazy loaded
>   module?**
>   This question arose in the Angular Module chapter when we
>   discussed the importance of keeping providers out of the SharedModule.
>
> Suppose we had listed the UserService in the module's providers (which
>   we did not). Suppose every module imports this SharedModule (which
>   they all do).
>
> When the app starts, Angular eagerly loads the AppModule and the
>   ContactModule.
>
> Both instances of the imported SharedModule would provide the
>   UserService. Angular registers one of them in the root app injector
>   (see above). Then some component injects UserService, Angular finds it
>   in the app root injector, and delivers the app-wide singleton
>   UserService. No problem.
>
> Now consider the HeroModule which is lazy loaded!
>
> When the router lazy loads the HeroModule, it creates a child injector
>   and registers the UserService provider with that child injector. The
>   child injector is not the root injector.
>
> When Angular creates a lazy HeroComponent, it must inject a
>   UserService. This time it finds a UserService provider in the lazy
>   module's child injector and creates a new instance of the UserService.
>   This is an entirely different UserService instance than the app-wide
>   singleton version that Angular injected in one of the eagerly loaded
>   components.
>
> That's almost certainly a mistake.
>
> > Prove it for yourself. Run the live example. Modify the SharedModule
> >     so that it provides the UserService rather than the CoreModule. Then
> >     toggle between the "Contact" and "Heroes" links a few times. The
> >     username goes bonkers as the Angular creates a new UserService
> >     instance each time.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-why-child-injector

> **Why does lazy loading create a child injector?**
>    Angular adds
>   @NgModule.providers to the application root injector ... unless the
>   module is lazy loaded. Then it creates a child injector and adds the
>   module's providers to the child injector.
>
> This means that a module behaves differently depending on whether it
>   is loaded during application start or lazy loaded later. Neglecting
>   that difference can lead to adverse consequences.
>
> Why doesn't Angular add lazy loaded providers to the app root injector
>   as it does for eagerly loaded modules? Why the inconsistency?
>
> The answer is grounded in a fundamental characteristic of the Angular
>   dependency injection system. An injector can add providers until it is
>   first used. Once an injector starts creating and delivering services,
>   its provider list is frozen. No new providers allowed.
>
> When an applications starts, Angular first configures the root
>   injector with the providers of all eagerly loaded modules before
>   creating its first component and injecting any of the provided
>   services. Once the application begins, the app root injector is closed
>   to new providers.
>
> Time passes. Application logic triggers lazy loading of a module.
>   Angular must add the lazy loaded module's providers to an injector
>   somewhere. It can't added them to the app root injector because that
>   injector is closed to new providers. So Angular creates a new child
>   injector for the lazy loaded module context.

Comment: Then how to share state data between lazy loaded module components?

Comment: Lazy loaded modules get the global services injected as well. Just provide the services at a non-lazy loaded module. Just the other way around doesn't work. Services of lazy loaded modules are only available for components and services in this module and other modules imported by them but not to non-lazy-loaded or other laty-loaded modul

Comment: that means if we import service in app.module.ts than it will available for all lazy loaded or non-lazy loaded module?? @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Ecactly . . . . .

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - It means a lazy loaded module will first look for the dependency in it's own root context & if it doesn't find it there then it will look into the application's root context. That's why we just call forRoot() in root module to import providers & don't import them again in lazy loaded modules. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @AnkushJain exactly. This way you ensure there will only be a single instance for these providers

Comment: Seems now the preferred way is just @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) ?

Answer (score 32):

As mentioned by @Günter Zöchbauer, this is explained the Angular docs, where lazy-loaded modules get their own instances of services. If a service is meant to be a true singleton, then you should either

**Provide it directly into the `AppModule`**

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [ SingletonService ]
})
class AppModule {}
```

These services are application-wide, even to lazy-loaded modules. So you don't need to add it to the `providers` of those lazy-loaded modules.

**Import a module that provides the service into the `AppModule`**

Note that a convention is to use a `forRoot`, as mentioned in [the docs][1]

```
@NgModule({
})
class CoreModule {
  static forRoot() {
    return {
      ngModule: SomeModule,
      providers: [SingletonService]
    }
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ CoreModule.forRoot() ]
})
class AppModule {}
```

The `forRoot` should only be called in the `AppModule` imports. This will insure that only the `AppModule` adds the provider. Any lazy-loaded modules have access to the same singleton service provided by the `AppModule`.

Comment: MyService should be singleton but not throught out the app. Rather through out the module where it is defined. I want to archive that only. Suppose I am creating a loosely coupled application with different module. Each module is independent with other. While integrating all module to my App I do not want to put all singleton Service to my AppModule.

Comment: Looking at the last sample, what if coremodule is declared in a lazy loaded module?  If I do coremodule then I must import it so its not lazy ...in other words -   can I use forroot for lazy loaded modules?

Comment: For reference, here is the link to the relevant page in the Angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#the-forroot-pattern

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by wrapping Mod1Page1 and Mod1Page2 components in one Mod1 component as child:

```
@Component({
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})
class Mod1Component {}

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component:Mod1Component,
    children:[
      {
        path : 'page1',
        component : Mod1Page1Component
      },
      {
        path : 'page2',
        component : Mod1Page2Component
      }
    ]
  }
];

const routedComponents = [Mod1Component,Mod1Page1Component, Mod1Page2Component];
```

[Plnkr link to solved fork](https://plnkr.co/edit/PgJDCi?p=preview)

Mod1Service will be created every time when you navigate to any Mod1Module's component from component of any other module, but when you navigate beetwen Mod1Module's component service will not be recreated.