# Angular2: Injectable as singleton

Tags: angular

I'm trying to inject an `@Injectable AppState` as a singleton:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppState {
  public user: string;

  constructor() {

  }
...
```

I've set it on `AppModule` as `provider`:

```
// Application wide providers
const APP_PROVIDERS = [
  AppState
];

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ App ],
  declarations: [
    App,
    ErrorComponent
  ],
  imports: [ // import Angular's modules
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true })
  ],
  providers: [
    APP_PROVIDERS
  ]
})
```

So, I've just created a `"submodule"`:

```
@NgModule({
  //...
  providers: [ UsersService, AppState ]
})
export default class LoginModule {
```

On `LoginComponent` I do:

```
export class Login implements OnInit {

    constructor(private appState: AppState) {}

    public doLogin():void {
        this.appState.user = this.form.value.mail;
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, on another component named `Profile`, it seems that `this.appState.user` is undefined.

```
@NgModule({
  //...
  providers: [ AppState ]
})
export default class ProfileModule { /... }

@Component({
  //...
})
export class Profile implements OnInit {

  constructor(private appState: AppState) {

  }

  ngOnInit():void {
    this.user = this.appState.user;  <<<<<<<<<<<<< it's undefined
  }
}
```

Why `this.appState.user` is undifined if I'set it before in another component?

Comment: You read it probably before it is set. Services (injectables) are singleton by default when you provide it only in non-lazy loaded modules. Only when you add it to `providers: [...]` of a component or directive or a module loaded with `loadChildren`, then there will be multiple instances.

Comment: I'm using `loadChildren`. Is there someway to get my goal?

Comment: Move the service out of the module loaded by `loadChildren` and add it to a module that is not lazy loaded.

Comment: This is already injected on `AppModule`. It's not lazy loaded. How could I get it from a module created using `loadChildren`?

Comment: If you provide it in `AppModule` **and** a module loaded using `loadChildren`, then to services and components loaded by the lazy loaded module the instance provided in the lazy loaded module will be injected and all other services and components will get the instance provided by `AppModule`. I don't think there is anything you can do about it.

Comment: So then, the scope I've described previously would have to work, doesn't it?

Comment: If it's only injected in `AppModule` and not in a module loaded with `loadChildren`, then there will always be only a single instance.

Comment: Is there some way to load `Injectables` as singleton on `loadChildren`ed modules/components?

Comment: Not one I'm aware of. Actually, I'm quite sure there isn't. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/40981772/217408