# Angular2: Lazy loading components and injectables as singletons

Tags: angular

Is there someway for providing `@Injectable`s as singletons loading components using `loadChildren` (lazy loading components)?

If not, is there some way to get it?

I'm asking it for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40981772/217408). According to that, it's not possible to inject an `@Injectable` as singletons on submodules.

I'm trying to inject an `@Injectable AppState` as a singleton:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppState {
  public user: string;

  constructor() {

  }
...
```

I've set it on `AppModule` as `provider`:

```
// Application wide providers
const APP_PROVIDERS = [
  AppState
];

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ App ],
  declarations: [
    App,
    ErrorComponent
  ],
  imports: [ // import Angular's modules
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true })
  ],
  providers: [
    APP_PROVIDERS
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(public appRef: ApplicationRef, public appState: AppState) {}
}
```

So, I've also created a `"submodule"`:

```
@NgModule({
  //...
  providers: [ AppState ]
})
export default class LoginModule {
```

On `LoginComponent` I do:

```
export class Login implements OnInit {

    constructor(private appState: AppState) {}

    public doLogin():void {
        this.appState.user = this.form.value.mail;
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, on another component named `Profile`, it seems that `this.appState.user` is undefined.

```
@NgModule({
  //...
  providers: [ AppState ]
})
export default class ProfileModule { /... }

@Component({
  //...
})
export class Profile implements OnInit {

  constructor(private appState: AppState) {

  }

  ngOnInit():void {
    this.user = this.appState.user;  <<<<<<<<<<<<< it's undefined
  }
}
```

Why `this.appState.user` is undifined if I'set it before in another component?

Comment: Don't provide it at the level of your lazy load _modules_. You'll have to provide it at the `app.module`level (or if you use one in your `core.module`).

Comment: What about [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40981772/217408)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That post explains everything you need to know. Any service declared in the lazy loaded module will only be a singleton for that module. Any service loaded in the root module will be a singleton throughout the app, including inside lazy loaded modules

Comment: I've edited the post. According to that. If I inject `AppState` on `AppModule (constructor(private appState: AppState))` it should be the same object (singleton) on `LoginComponent` and `ProfileComponent`, shouldn't it? Nevertheless, `this.appState.user` is always `undefined` regardless of whether on `LoginComponent` have assigned it...

Comment: @Jordi Why you're declaring `AppState` in providers array of `ProfileModule`  and `LoginModule`? Have you tried to declare it only in `AppModule`?

Answer (score 1):

All `@Injectable()` services are singletons. Loading components is the job of the router, not the service.